# Sync Document to iCloud

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, icloud

I have a question to ask about an `iCloud` syncing problem. I have an application which is installed in two devices `iPhone` and `iPad`. In `iPhone` I am updating the `iCloud` document which is supposed to reflect in the `iPad` but what happens is that when I update the document in `iPhone`, the `iPad` application stops working saying: `"The existing document failed to open"`. What would be the problem? I am following this links for `iCloud` Storage:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/6015/beginning-icloud-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-1

and

http://www.raywenderlich.com/6031/beginning-icloud-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-2

Answer (score 2):

First and foremost you need to use `setUbiquitous` function of `NSFileManager` to move documents to/from iCloud. I am assuming you do.

Typically if from one device you moved a document to local sandbox then the other device would not be able to open it with a URL still pointing to iCloud.

The Local vs. iCloud preference should be presented to the user upfront, and users should be able to change it afterwards.

However your app needs to deal with the scenario when it is pulled into local storage from one device (on the same apple id). On the other device, upon noticing the document is moved from the iCloud, you need to present a sensible prompt/indication to the user, rather than reporting it as an error.

There are also well documented scenarios on how you would resolve merge conflicts.

There are certain Apple requirements and guidelines you need to follow if you want to manage your documents across iCloud.

Please read the definitive guide to document based applications on IOS [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/DataManagement/Conceptual/DocumentBasedAppPGiOS/Introduction/Introduction.html).